¿Cómo poner título de un marker en Google Maps con la API de Javascript?
Estoy utilizando la API de Google Maps en conjunto con los componentes de Angular de la dependencia @angular/google-maps, al implementar el marker dentro de un mapa me gustaría poner el nombre de mi negocio pero al ponerle la propiedad title sirve solamente como un elemento para la accesibilidad...
Me gustaría poder agregar el título como la siguiente imagen:

De esta forma tengo el mapa actualmente:

Este es el TS del componente:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap, MapAdvancedMarker  } from '@angular/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [GoogleMap, MapAdvancedMarker],
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrl: './footer.component.scss',
})
export class FooterComponent {
  companyPosition = { lat: 6.1912182261743745, lng: -75.57700406318196 };


  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    center: this.companyPosition,
    zoom: 17,
  };

  markerOptions: google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElementOptions = {
    title: ('Control Legal'),
    position: this.companyPosition
  };
}


Y este es el template del mismo componente:
<google-map [options]="options" width="100%" mapId="44527b7e59b94241">
    <map-advanced-marker [options]="markerOptions"></map-advanced-marker>
</google-map>

Consulté a través de toda la documentación de Google API Javascript y los Advanced Markers pero no pude encontrar nada.

En lugar de utilizar title, tienes que usar label, ya sea en TS o directamente en el HTML.

Directamente:

<google-map height="300px" width="550px" [options]="options">
  <map-advanced-marker
    #marker="mapMarker"
    [position]="coords"
    [label]="'Plaza Constitución'"
  />
</google-map>


Estableciendo el marcador desde el componente:

<map-advanced-marker #marker="mapMarker" [options]="markerOptions" />

markerOptions: google.maps.AdvancedMarkerElementOptions = {
  label: 'Plaza Constitución',
  position: { ...this.coords },
};

Hay que mencionar que esta opción esta obsoleta desde el

